# Javascript posting array displaying syntax wrong

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have actionresult as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRoomFeature(string[] selectedFeatures, int RoomID)
{
    return View();
}
```

**Javascript Ajax**

```
var selectedFeatures = [];

$('input.Hotelfeature:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    selectedFeatures.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("AddRoomFeature", "HotelRoom")',
    data: {
        selectedFeatures: JSON.stringify(selectedFeatures),
        RoomID: $("#RoomID").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

**Question:**

If i post selectedFeatures to actionresult,

**selectedFeatures** displays value as **["\1",\"2\"]**

Normally value should display as **"1","2"** in string array.

Where i miss in ajax code ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedFeatures` is received as a single string value because you're using `JSON.stringify` on the actual array before sending the ajax request. When you're making a jQuery ajax request you can specify the data to be sent to the server with plain JavaScript object. Manual serialization is not needed. The data is converted to a query string or a request body. The default content type is `application/form-url-encoded`.

So, to work your code should become:

```
var selectedFeatures = [];

$('input.Hotelfeature:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    selectedFeatures.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("AddRoomFeature", "HotelRoom")',
    data: {
        selectedFeatures: selectedFeatures, // Note the missing JSON.stringify
        RoomID: $("#RoomID").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Almost :). Parameter `selectedFeatures` will be `null`. You need to add the `traditional: true,` ajax option to make this work